# Restore Fragments within a FragmentStatePagerAdapter (i.e. remember list position)

Tags: android, android-fragments, restore, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am using a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` as using a `ViewPager` with a `FragmentPagerAdapter` (which has many pages) was causing memory issues.

This works well, however I'd like to be able to restore pages (`ListFragments`) to their original position when the Fragment is recreated. This seems straightforward but I'm not having much luck achieving it.

Does anyone have any tips?

Thanks